# Discord API, get_member(user_id) errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code and i am really curious about why it is not working. The problem is in `k = discord.Server.get_member(j)` it says

> "TypeError: get_member() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'".

This code uses [discord.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/discord.py):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('/sendpm'):
    print(message.author)
    j = message.content.replace('/sendpm ', '')
    print(j)
    j = j.replace('@', '')
    j = j.replace('<', '')
    j = j.replace('>', '')
    j = j.replace('!', '')
    print(l)
    k = discord.Server.get_member(j) #problem is here
    await client.send_message(await client.start_private_message(k), spammsg)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'sent' + message.author.mention)
```

Comment: for any future readers: discord.py has been discontinued: https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is accessing a method of `discord.Server` as if it was a static method:

```
k = discord.Server.get_member(j)
```

Function [`get_member` is defined as](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v0.13.0/discord/server.py#L132):

```
def get_member(self, user_id):
```

It accepts `self` as the first argument because it is meant to be called on an instance, e.g.:

```
server = discord.Server()
server.get_member(user_id)
```

Whether that is the correct way to get a `Server` instance I do not know. [This example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/new_member.py) seems to have a different way to get to a server instance:

> ```
> @client.event
> async def on_member_join(member):
>     server = member.server
>     fmt = 'Welcome {0.mention} to {1.name}!'
>     await client.send_message(server, fmt.format(member, server))
> ```